# How to create a WPF application which works both in Windows and Web

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am going to start a new (Right-To-Left) WPF project and the Main reason is to provide a single UI for the application in Windows and Web.

What Should I consider?

Which WPF Controls should/shouln't (can/can't) I use?

Do I Have to Use Silverlight? (I'm not interest)

Should I use XBAP project orWindows Project with Page base modules?

TIA

Comment: You can't use WPF on the web. Silverlight could be a way to go, but desktop support isn't all there, if I recall correctly. A better approach might be to have the same business logic for your desktop and web app and then build separate UIs.

Comment: @Anna, I checked that XBAP project runs in windows just like evry other asp.net web applications, and also Windows (Page-base) project are also usable within a LAN, so why do you say that it's impossible? If I have to use silverlight it's not important, but if it is totaly impossible it's another disscussion? is it possible ornot? and How to?

Comment: I forgot about XBAP, to be honest. One problem with it is that it's Windows-only. Another issue is that it's not a desktop application. You won't be able to run it outside of Internet Explorer. In that case, why not just build a normal web app? (I assume you're talking about reusing the same project as a desktop app and a web app. That I'm pretty sure isn't possible, but if I'm wrong I'm sure someone will correct me. :))

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are indeed XBAP (WPF Browser App) and SilverLight.

You can easily google to find lots of comparisons, here is a [short and simple one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2008/05/06/when-should-i-use-wpf-vs-silverlight.aspx).

You main decision factor is your target audience. Do you want to support the Apple platform and maybe even Linux? Then use SilverLight.

If you're sure you only have Windows clients (Web and Desktop) you could use the more powerful WPF. But do write the WBA first so you don't run into permission issues later.